# PHP - Make HTML table using 2D Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like bellow and the data in the array is bit large,

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1 [cyear] => 2016 [cmonth] => 1 [cmonthname] => January [cday] => 1 [cdayname] => Friday [ctime] => 9:00 [status] => 6 [notes] => )
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 2 [cyear] => 2016 [cmonth] => 1 [cmonthname] => January [cday] => 1 [cdayname] => Friday [ctime] => 9:15 [status] => 1 [notes] => )
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 3 [cyear] => 2016 [cmonth] => 1 [cmonthname] => January [cday] => 1 [cdayname] => Friday [ctime] => 9:30 [status] => 1 [notes] => )
        [3] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 4 [cyear] => 2016 [cmonth] => 1 [cmonthname] => January [cday] => 1 [cdayname] => Friday [ctime] => 9:45 [status] => 1 [notes] => )
        [4] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 5 [cyear] => 2016 [cmonth] => 1 [cmonthname] => January [cday] => 1 [cdayname] => Friday [ctime] => 10:00 [status] => 1 [notes] => )
        [5] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 6 [cyear] => 2016 [cmonth] => 1 [cmonthname] => January [cday] => 1 [cdayname] => Friday [ctime] => 10:15 [status] => 1 [notes] => )
```

The idea behind this,

each array represents a given time slot (15mins) from 9.00AM to 5.00PM

which means for one hour there are 04 number of arrays/stdClass Objects (9:00, 9:15, 9:30, 9:45)

for a day there are 32 arrays/stdClass Objects 9.00AM to 5.00PM -> 8 hours
so 8*4 = 32

So for February of 2016, there are 928 (32*29) arrays/stdClass Objects 
and you can

[download the full data array here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4daLf2xHkWPdmVHYXhpTDN5bTA/view?usp=sharing)

Using this I want to make a HTML table like below,

[image]

Green row is the days (1 to 29 of 2016, Feb)

Yellow column is timeslots (9.00AM to 4.45PM)

1s are the status of each array/stdClass Objects

Comment: Did I miss a question somewhere here?

Comment: I don't get the question in this. What are you asking for? How to print the table?

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned it as " I want to make a HTML table like below" anyway yes I want to make the table in the image using the array

Comment: It seems like there is a much simpler (and server friendly) way to accomplish this using php time(), date() and strtotime() functions and while loops. Any comments or statuses could be stored in a mysql table with a timestamp. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML tends to be much easier to print when you can print horizontal, then vertical, so start with putting it into a grid.

```
$newArray=[][];
foreach($hugeArray as $block)
    $newArray[$block["ctime"]][$block["cday"]]=$block["status"];
```

Now you can double loop to print. (Assuming table is used and excluding first row):

```
foreach($newArray as $ctime=>$smalArray)
{
    print("<tr><td>".$ctime."</td>");
    foreach($smalArray as $cday => $status)
        print("<td>".$status."</td>");
    print("</tr>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Appreciate your hand for this. your algorithm is working :))